# error installing php dependencies on ubuntu

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, php, lamp

I have a vps with `linux ubuntu 20.04` LTS installed, I also installed the lamp stack to upload my web projects, php with version 7.4, now I need to install some more php libraries for example: `php-gd` so run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

but when installing I get the following error: `php7.4-cli : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17 is to be installed`

and actually it won't let me install anything else, because it always throws me that error.. any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a dependency issue with the php7.4-cli, here is things you can do to try to fix that, first do an update and upgrade

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then clear your cache

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4-gd
```

If that still dont work we can try removing the conflicting package

```
sudo apt remove php7.4-cli
sudo apt install php7.4-gd
```

If not we can still force the install `sudo apt install php7.4-gd --allow-downgrades`